# Making ImageView appear on top of other elements but below status and navigation bar

Tags: android, view

I have a very peculiar use-case here I am trying to solve for. I have the following layout:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/content_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/header_bar"
        layout="@layout/section_header" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/wallpaper_grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/wallpaper_grid_padding_top"
        android:scrollbarSize="@dimen/grid_padding"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        android:scrollbarThumbVertical="?android:textColorTertiary"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <androidx.core.widget.ContentLoadingProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loading_indicator"
        style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.ProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:indeterminate="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/template_image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Now this view above has a header, and a grid containing a bunch of thumbnails. What I am doing is, when I click on any thumbnail, the thumbnail expands (with animation) and image is populated in the `ImageView` with ID: `template_image_view`. Now, the issue is, this `ImageView` is not full screen, by full screen, I mean below the status and navigation bar as well. If I try to make it go full screen by setting

`android:translationZ="-1dp"` then this view goes below the recycler view grid as well which I don't want. I would want that this TextView stays above all other elements but below the status and navigation bar (so that it gives the impression that it's completely occupying the full screen).

Is there a way to do this?